# what statistics should I use?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, spss, nonparametric

I did an experiment by feeding three diets (PK, HG and Control (C)) to an insect species. These three diets were offered on two different substrates (PAM, PDA). And I used two parameters to measure which diet is best, 1) developmental time of insect, 2) No. of adults reaching to adulthood. 
Now I was wondering which test statistics I should use, whether 3x2 contingency table or something else ?
My aim is to find out insects perform better on which diet (PK, HG, C) and on what kind of substrate (PAM, PDA) ?

Here is my data;

```
Treatment   LPAM    APAM    LPDA    APDA
PK  20  20  19  5
PK  19  18  18  11
PK  19  19  20  9
PK  21  18  21  8
PK  20  20  19  7
PK  20  19  19  5
PK  19  19  21  6
PK  20  20  21  3
PK  21  18  20  10
PK  20  17  20  9
PK  19  18  19  12
PK  20  19  20  8
PK  21  19  19  6
PK  21  20  20  7
PK  20  18  20  5
HG  23  14  23  2
HG  24  15  25  1
HG  25  16  22  4
HG  25  14  23  4
HG  25  12  26  1
HG  24  13  25  1
HG  24  15  23  1
HG  23  14  22  3
HG  24  14  22  4
HG  25  13  19  1
HG  25  13  19  5
HG  23  13  19  1
HG  25  12  24  3
HG  24  12  25  5
HG  25  14  26  2
C   41  2   0   0
C   42  1   0   0
C   42  1   0   0
C   41  1   0   0
C   42  2   0   0
C   42  1   0   0
C   43  2   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
C   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: How many subjects have you examined in each (diet, substrate) group? Have you explored the distributional properties of the two performance variables in each (diet, substrate) group?... Tell us more about the data.

Comment: Sounds like a classic two way ANOVA analysis might be applicable here

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick response; here I've attached my data:

Comment: data is not normally distributed

Comment: Maybe more importantly, the data appear to be counts with a portion of those counts as zeros.